# Why can I make a numpy array that's (apparently) bigger than my computer's memory?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, scipy, sparse-matrix

When I run code below:

```
import scipy.sparse
x = scipy.sparse.random(100000, 100000, 1e-4)
y = x.toarray()
print(y.nbytes)
```

I get an output of 80000000000 bytes = 80 GB. And yet I am using a Macbook Air with only 4 GB of RAM. Can someone explain how I am (apparently) creating a NumPy array larger than my memory size? Is `y` somehow a view of `x`, rather than a copy? I didn't find anything about this in the `scipy.sparse` documentation. Unsurprisingly if I do something like `y.copy()` I crash Python... I can't expect to do something to an array of size 10^10. Thanks!

Versions:
Python 3.5.2 via Anaconda 4.1.1, SciPy 0.17.1, NumPy 1.11.1.

Comment: I tried to create `np.zeros` array with `nbytes` close to 40GB. but the actually memory used is less than 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

This is because numpy doesn't actually allocate all that space. Most likely sparse arrays and matrices are represented with [triplets, linked nodes](http://btechsmartclass.com/DS/U1_T14.html) or some other means of ignoring all the empty space between. The bytes are calculated based on the assigned dimensions of the matrix/array, not the actual data in memory.

Comment: The array `x` is a sparse matrix type and so what you said above certainly applies. But to get `y` I explicitly converted it from sparse to dense form with [`toarray()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.spmatrix.toarray.html#scipy.sparse.spmatrix.toarray). That's why I am confused.

Comment: You're still using numpy types. `toarray()` doesn't convert it to a native python list, hence why you're able to access `.nbytes` on it. Until it's converted to native python lists, it's probably using as sparse a representation as possible to save space.